# How to plot a x bar control chart?

Tags: plotting

Does anyone know how to plot a [x bar control chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbar_and_R_chart)?
With mu=12.5, sigma=.8?

I have searched all over mathematica documentation center but still couldn't figure out how?

Comment: I think it might help to clarify what you want. Can you give some more details on what you would like to see as your ourput?

Comment: I want to plot multiple parallel horizontal lines. Seems to be pretty simple stuff, but couldn't figure out how. Thanks!

Comment: Please include some kind of example.  A chart graphic found with e.g. Google is fine, but please note the *specific* elements you wish to replicate.  If all else fails draw a chart and take a picture of it.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply wish to produce a chart such as
[Control chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_chart)

```
controlchart[data_,mu_,sigma_,num_,opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=
ListLinePlot[
data,
GridLines->{None,{mu-num sigma, mu,mu+ num sigma}},
GridLinesStyle->Directive[Red, Dashed],
Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts},Options[ListLinePlot]]]
]
```

So for your case: `controlchart[data, 12.5,8,2]`, if you want 2 standard deviation control limits. If you want to format the lines individually, then you can write your own code with lines in `Epilog`.

If, however, you wish the more complex cusum control charts with sepcification of more compex control limits that is more complex.